# Can a super class method implementation depend on child class field

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I am in a situation as follows.

I have an interface A which is inherited by class B,C,D (B,C,D implements A).

```
  public interface A{
        public String someMethod();
    }

    class B implements A{
        ObjectType1 model;

        @Override
        public String someMethod(){
            if(model instanceof X){
                System.out.print(true);
            }
        }
    }

    class C implements A{
         ObjectType2 model;

        @Override
        public String someMethod(){
            if(model instanceof X){
                System.out.print(true);
            }
    }

    class D implements A{
     ObjectType3 model;

        @Override
        public String someMethod(){
            if(model instanceof X){
                System.out.print(true);
            }
    }
```

As you can see all method implementations are the same. So I am duplicating code. My plan was to move the method to A and make A an abstract class. But the problem is my method depends on the model field. So what would be my options to make this code better?

bdw class A,B,C extends and implements other classes too.

EDIT

modification in code. check field

Comment: If you turn interface A to an abstract class (or just a parent class) it can also have the model field. You can declare it protected, and subclasses will have access to it. Why would that be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem related to the `model` field transforming the interface `A` into an abstract class.

There is no need to reimplement the method in the subclasses if it is the same, unless you want to change its behavior (override it).

```
public abstract class A {

    // Make it protected so it can accessible by subclasses
    protected Object model;

    // Common behavior that will be inherited by subclasses
    public String someMethod() {
        if (model instanceof X) {
            return "x";
        } else {
            return "not x";
        }
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    // Subclasses may access superclasses fields if protected or public.
    public void someOtherMethod() {
        System.out.println(super.model.toString());
    }

}

public class C extends A {

    // You may wish to override a parent's method behavior
    @Override
    public String someMethod() {
        return "subclass implements it different";
    }

}
```

---

For your new code example, if you really want to do that in a procedural way you can create an abstract superclass `ObjectType` and then it will be accessible for the parent as well.

However I wouldn't do that. It seems to me that in doing so is the very opposite of what object orientation tries to solve.

By using a subclass to define the behavior, you wouldn't need to do it in a procedural logic. That's precisely then point of using objects, inheritance and overriding/implementing behavior as needed.

Comment: would this affect any exiting code written against class A?

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent class A with said field, and said function. Have the other classes extend A. No need to override them if they function the same.

Answer (score 0):

To deduplicate, you can either make A an abstract class and move the implementation of the method and the field there, or create an abstract class, say E, that implements the interface with that method and field and then have B, C and D extend that class E.

For the more general question of depending on a subclass's field, you can create an abstract method getModel which the subclasses decide how to implement -- by returning a model field or doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 you could use `default` method in interface A, with a getter method for  model.

```
 public interface A{
        default public String someMethod() {
            if(getModel() instanceof X){
                System.out.print(true);
            }
        }

       public Object model getModel();
}
```

Then implement `getModel` method in all child interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do this you must have `model` to be of the same (basic) type in all derived objects. If it were of the same type there's a case for putting the `model` to a base class. Anyway if they are of different derived types you would need to have an accessor to get it.

```
 interface B {
     BaseModel getModel();

     default public strict doSomething() {
          BaseModel m = getModel();

          // do something with m
     }
 }

 class D implements B {
      DerivedModel model;

      public getModel() {
           return model;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I was given a chance to refactor it, I will follow below approach, leveraging Java 8 [Default Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html):

```
interface A {
    default String someMethod(X objectType) {
        if (objectType instanceof X) {
            System.out.println(true);
        }
        // return something, for now returning class
        return objectType.getClass().toString();
    }
}

class B implements A {
    @Override
    public String someMethod(X objectType) {
        if (objectType instanceof X) {
            System.out.println(true);
        }
        // return "Hello"
        return "Hello";
    }
}

class C implements A {}

class D implements A {}
```

**Usage:**

```
public class Main implements A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();
        D d = new D();
        Main main = new Main();

        main.call(b);
        main.call(c);
        main.call(d);
    }

    public void call(A clazz) {
        ObjectType1 objectType1 = new ObjectType1();
        String type = clazz.someMethod(objectType1);
        System.out.println(type);
    }
}

interface X {
}

class ObjectType1 implements X {

}
```